# Extract item price from HTML

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm struggling to get the price from the following HTML

```html
<span class="pricing__now" itemprop="price">7.99</span>
```

I'm trying to extract the "7.99" from the above example.
I've tried `HTML.getElementsByClassName("pricing__now")(0).innertext`
but drawing blank.

Any help, kindly received.

Many thanks in advance.

Ian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be easier to give better advice if we can see more HTML and also the URL if possible. Here are some tips:

1) You need to ensure you have the right index

To check you have the right index, right click inspect element the press Ctrl + F to bring up the HTML search box and enter `.pricing__now`. Check how many matches there are and at which index your desired match is.

2) Ensure the page has loaded with this value when you try to access. So before trying to access, if using IE, ensure you have:

```
While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
```

after your `navigate2` line

3) You can also use combined CSS selectors to be more specific

```
ie.document.querySelector(".pricing__now[itemprop=price]").innerText
```

Comment: Does the class name appear more than once?

Comment: @alowflyingpig A valid point which is why I am asking OP to check the index. If so, they will need to amend the index and also use querySelectorAll for point 3 e.g. ie.document.querySelector(".pricing__now[itemprop=price]").item(1).innerText

Comment: Remember to subtract one from number in search box results as that is indexed from 1

Comment: (0) = first time it appears, (1) = second time it appears, etc

Comment: QHarr -Thank you `.querySelector(".pricing__now[itemprop=price]").innerText` is perfect.  Worked a treat. Thanks.

Comment: So I need more html or an URL.

Comment: Blimey, that was quick.  The HTML is `<span class="pricing__now" itemprop="price">22.00</span>` There are too may characters to add the full pricing element.

Comment: [link](https://www.superdrug.com/Calvin-Klein/CK-Obsession-Men-Eau-de-Toilette-125ml/p/100396) as an example.  Thanks.

Comment: I've mainly been trying variances on `getElementsByClassName` with `HTML.getElementsByClassName("pricing__now")(0).outerText` and `HTML.getElementsByClassName("pricing__now")(0).innertext` and `HTML.getElementsByClassName("pricing__now")(0).Value` but drawing blanks.

Comment: Yes, as I'm able to get the name with `HTML.getElementsByClassName("pdp__productName")(0).innertext`

Comment: It’s just taking a long time for me. The selector is still correct.

Comment: Thanks for that.  So that's using i.e. to load the page. is it possible to extract direct from the html using `With http
            .Open "GET", lnk, False
            .send
            HTML.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With` ?...

Comment: Let me see as xmlhttp was timing out

Comment: Thanks, I was just about to add I'm using XMLHTTP60

Comment: xmlhttp is timing out for me. Not sure if this is a temporary thing or the site blocks access in this way. Have you been able to retrieve content via xmlhttp?

Comment: Yes.  I'm able to get the Item name but not the price. I tried your ie method and was able to extract the price, but I have problems with this method as I have to cycle through hundreds of urls and it often falls over when trying to upload the url.

Comment: It won't let me access. I am now getting access denied. If you pastebin your entire response html I can look to see how the html returned differs. Using a javascript xmlhttp I can see that the required data sits in a json string within a script tag associated with pageLoaded event

Comment: Here's my code. [https://pastebin.com/nSaSBEpk](https://pastebin.com/nSaSBEpk) I don't want to be too much of a strain on your time though QHarr.  I'm sure I could muddle through using your help earlier. Thanks again though.

Comment: It’s fine. What I can still see with xmlhttp is I am getting an imcompletely “loaded” response. The data is present however, as I said, in a Json string. I will write something quickly.

Comment: I cannot see, currently, a reliable way to ensure that enough content is returned by xmlhttp to select from. I will need to have a look later. Is there an API available?

Comment: Don't worry about it.  I'll try using the ie method.  Thank you so much for your help though. It's been a steep learning curve for me, but enjoyable none-the-less. Thank you.